# Angular parameters not being hidden

Tags: angular

I am trying to hide url parameters by using `skipLocationChange=true` however it does not seem to be working. My url looks like this `http://localhost:4200/details`.

I am navigating like this `this.router.navigate(['/details', { caseInfo: JSON.stringify(this.caseInfo), skipLocationChange:true }]);` and my route structure is as follows `{ path: 'details', component: DetailsComponent }`

Any ideas?

Comment: I've deleted my past answer because you just did a typo ;)

Comment: Can you try with `skipLocationChange` outside of square bracket ? 

`this.router.navigate(['/details', { caseInfo: JSON.stringify(this.caseInfo)], { skipLocationChange:true });`

Comment: That's it, thanks @Zooly, please post as answer and I'll mark as correct

Comment: Nice, glad to read it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use options object outside of the square brackets of the route.

`this.router.navigate(['/details', { caseInfo: JSON.stringify(this.caseInfo)], { skipLocationChange:true });`